# How to fix warnings in the error list for auto-created interface functions?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compiler-warnings

I used ILSpy on an interop dll so that I could just compile the code into my exe.  But for every function and property in that code, the IDE and Compiler warns me that "Function/Property 'xxx' doesn't return a value on all code paths." It works fine, it's just annoying to have all those warnings in my error list and the compiler output. Can I put a "Return Nothing" there? Or do I need to just leave it alone?  Here's what it looks like:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace QBXMLRP2Lib
<ComImport, TypeLibType(CShort(2)), Guid("45F5708E-3B43-4FA8-BE7E-A5F1849214CB"), ClassInterface(CShort(0))> _
Public Class RequestProcessor2Class
    Implements RequestProcessor2
    Implements IRequestProcessor3
    Implements IRequestProcessor4

    Public Function BeginSession(qbFileName As String, reqFileMode As QBFileMode) As String Implements IRequestProcessor3.BeginSession

    End Function

    Public Sub CloseConnection() Implements IRequestProcessor3.CloseConnection

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionType As QBXMLRPConnectionType Implements IRequestProcessor3.ConnectionType
        Get

        End Get
    End Property
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: if the warning is telling you that it does not properly it's telling you that the method expects the key word `return` if you are not wanting to return anything then the method should be void

Comment: `" used ILSpy on an interop dll so that I could just compile the code into my exe."`- That is the entire point of  Embed Interop Types from reference's properties.

Comment: Neither of these comments make sense to me.  +MethodMan, I know it's expecting the Return keyword. That's why I asked if I could put "Return Nothing" in there.  I can't change it from a function to a method because then it wouldn't compile (if that's what you meant by "should be void").  +TnTinMn What is the entire point of Embed Interop Types? I wasn't able to figure out what you were trying to tell me.

Comment: You are using a decompiler to extract code from a library that your would normally just reference.  Your stated purpose of this is include this code as part of your project's assembly.Just add a project reference to the original ddl.  In the Solution Explorer, Show all Files and expand the References node.  Select the dll, and right-click -> Show Properties.  Set "Embed Interop Types to True.

Comment: @TnTinMn ah. I get it. I never realized that option existed. Just read Scott Hanselman's article on it and now have my palm print on my forehead. If you make it an answer, i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used ILSpy on an interop dll so that I could just compile the code
>   into my exe.

This is the purpose of setting "Embed Interop Types" to True.

Add the Dll as project reference.  From the Solution Explorer, click the show all files button and expand the References node.  Select the dll in question and right-click on it an select Show Properties.  Set the "Embed Interop Types" to True.  This will cause the compiler to embed any needed library types to be embedded into your program.

I would recommend leaving this set to False during debugging so that you have access to all type information in the referenced dll.  If it is set to True, you can only access the type information that your code referenced prior to compiling and it makes using "Edit and Continue a pain if you want to reference new type information.